# Can't see internal drive when using Ubuntu's LiveUSB

Tags: 18.04, live-usb, gparted, ssd, fdisk

I have a laptop which has a 256GB internal drive with Windows 10 Enterprise installed on it and it works fine.

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.02.  I have created a LiveUSB and can boot into the OS by selecting the "Try without installing" option.

However, when I try to install Ubuntu, I get a message saying that I do not have enough storage space.  I have tried `sudo fdisk -l`, but it does not list the 256GB drive.  I have also tried using gparted, and it too does not list the 256GB drive.

The laptop is a Dell Latitude 7490.

**EDIT 1:**

To shut down Windows 10, I opened the command line and typed `shutdown /s /f /t 0`

`sudo fdisk -l` shows me the following:

[image]

`sudo parted -l` shows me the following:

[image]

Comment: You need to shut up Windows properly. What does `sudo parted -l` show?

Comment: Good point, will try that and update the question accordingly in a few moments.

Comment: Added details on how I shut down Windows and what `fdisk -l` and `parted -l` show.

Comment: You have a variable Windows partition, I don't remember how it's called correctly. Ubuntu can't use it.

Comment: When running the installer did you use "Something else"? If so was the Windows partition listed? when installing using Something else make sure the device for boot loader installation is the drive, (not partition), you are installing to.

Comment: I don't get the option to select "Something else" which I usually do get on older computers.  With this new computer, it just says 'You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu.  This computer has only 8.1 GB'.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: this page by Dell may be helpful. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en#Things_to_know

Comment: try to to shutdown Windows again and use the menu button while holding the SHIFT key when clicking “Shutdown” option. You could also try to disable Fast-Boot in windows.

Comment: Also, you might need to disable hibernation, I think, in Windows. At least you'd need to do that to access the partition.

Comment: @oshirowanen: if you boot to try, can you see, (and mount), your internal drive in Disks?

Comment: @C.S. the comment is a link. Read and find out why it doesn't work for the rest of us.

Comment: did you try to make a **Un-allocated space** on Legacy or UEFI support OS before you select the **Install Ubuntu** option??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things need to be done:

- Create empty space on Windows
- Turn off Fast Startup

## Create empty space on Windows

The first step is to allocate enough space for Ubuntu. With your 250 GB drive 50 GB to 100 GB could be a good balance for Ubuntu.

In Windows 10 start menu type "`Disk Management`" and a screen like this appears:

[image: Win 10 Disk Management.png]

- On this machine "Disk 1" is used to store 3 Ubuntu partitions and one shared Windows/Ubuntu data partition.
- In order to create extra Ubuntu partitions, the Windows Partition was shrunk from 477 GB to 363 GB.
- Make sure you create empty space at least 20 GB in size however 50 GB to 100 GB would probably suit your needs.
- To create empty space you need to shrink the size of the Windows 10 partition.
- Do not worry about creating a partition in the empty space. Ubuntu Installer will do that for you.

---

## Turn off Fast Startup

When you boot your computer Windows 10 has a feature to speed up the boot process. This feature though makes it impossible fir Ubuntu to access Windows (NTFS) partitions because they are "locked".

In Windows 10 click the start menu and type "`Power Options`". In the screen that appears click **Choose what the power buttons do**:

[image: Win 10 Fast Startup.png]

- Notice the check mark next to **Turn on fast startup (recommended)**. Uncheck it.
- Note to keep **Hibernate** unchecked.